# Denseness of a Preimage

Tags: general-topology

Let $F:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ and  $A\subset \mathbb{R}$, where $A$ is a dense set on $\mathbb{R}$ ,and $F$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R^2} $.

Is $F^{-1}(A)$ a dense set on $\mathbb{R^2}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily.

$F^{-1}(A)$ can even be empty.

For example, suppose $F$ is constant and the image point doesn't lie in $A$.

Comment: So, $F$ must be forcely biyective with $A$ to be true ?

Comment: You may want to consider adding a requirement that $A$ meets $F(\mathbb R^2)$, possibly in a nondegenerate set, or that $A$ is dense in $F(\mathbb R^2)$. The stated conditions are not enough. What can you show? You're the one trying to prove this, not me ;)

Comment: Thank you , think I see clearer now